# How do you allow a user to retrieve values from a list in Java?

Tags: java, list

I created a list in a FlightBookingSystem Java Class, as you can see below:

```java
public List<Flight> getFlights() {
    List<Flight> out = new ArrayList<>(flights.values());
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(out);
}
```

Which I imported from a text file show below:

```
1::LX2500::Birmingham::Munich::2020-11-25::

2::LX2500::Denmark::London::2021-07-01::

3::LY2380::London::France::2021-06-28::
```

It's a basic text file which holds the information for each flight

Here is the code I wish to adjust:

```java
public Flight execute(FlightBookingSystem flightBookingSystem, int id)
        throws FlightBookingSystemException {
    List<Flight> flights = flightBookingSystem.getFlights();
    for (Flight Flight : flights) {
        if (Flight.getFlightNumber() == flightNumber) {
            System.out.println(Flight.getFlightNumber() + " flight(s)");
            return flights.get(id);
        }
        System.out.println(((Flight) flights).getFlightNumber() + " flight(s)");

    }
    return flights.get(id);
}
```

How do I change that code so that it allows the user to retrieve one single record from the text file?

Comment: For `Flight.getFlightNumber()== flightNumber`, where does the `flightNumber` come from?

Comment: Just remember: users don't retrieve anything from a list. Only the program can do that.

Comment: The flightNumber is called from another class called Flight.java

Answer (score 1):

Why not to retrieve all and get the one you want by key or id using `HashMap`  ?

If you still want the other option, you can read the text file line by line, and check if it `startsWith(...)` and the to retrieve this line.

Code example:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)))
{
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
       // Add here 'if' condition and parse your line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing. Your title states:

```
How do you allow a user to retrieve values from a list in Java?
```

and the very last line of your post states:

```
How do I change that code so that it allows the user to retrieve
one single record from the text file?
```

Which is it, from a List or from a text file?

If it's from a List because you already have the mechanism available then is could be something similar to this:

```
public String getFlightInfo(String flightNumber) {
    List<Flight> flights = FlightBookingSystem.getFlights();
    for (Flight flite : flights) {
        if(flite.getFlightNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(flightNumber)){
            return flite.toString();
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>Flight number <font color=red><b>" 
            + flightNumber + "</b></font> could not be found!</html>", "Flight Not "
            + "Found", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    return null;
}
```

The code above assumes you have an overriden `toString()` method applied to the **Flight** class. If you don't then create one.

If it's actually from file then it **could** be something like this:

```
public String getFlightInfo(String flightNumber) {
    // 'Try With Resouces' to auto-close reader.
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Flights.txt"))) {
        String fileLine = "";
        while ((fileLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileLine = fileLine.trim();
            // If by chance the file line read in is blank then skip it.
            if (fileLine.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            // First, remove the double colons at the end of line (if any). 
            if (fileLine.endsWith("::")) {
                fileLine = fileLine.substring(0, fileLine.lastIndexOf("::")).trim();
            }
            /* Split each read in file line based on a double colon delimiter. 
               The "\\s*" within the regex for the split method handles any 
               cases where the might be one or more whitespaces before or after 
               the double-colon delimiter.                */
            String[] lineParts = fileLine.split("\\s*\\:\\:\\s*");
            if(lineParts[1].equalsIgnoreCase(flightNumber)){
                // At this point you could just return the line, for example:
                // return fileLine;
                // or you can return a string with a little more structure:
                return new StringBuilder("Flight ID: ").append(lineParts[0])
                        .append(", Flight #: ").append(lineParts[1]).append(", From: ")
                        .append(lineParts[2]).append(", To: ").append(lineParts[3])
                        .append(", Date: ").append(lineParts[4]).toString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>Flight number <font color=red><b>" 
            + flightNumber + "</b></font> could not be found!</html>", "Flight Not "
            + "Found", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I created the list from the text file. The text file was just used to create the list